# Conversion of resultset to Java model slow for a million records

Tags: java, select, records, bulk

This is what my code looks like. The query executes in less than a minute, but the while loop takes more than 2 hours to finish! I have around 800,000 records. Can you please let me know the best way to save in the reportModelList. I can even switch to Hibernate if required.

```
PreparedStatement ps =connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
try{
while (rs.next()) {
ReportModel t = new ReportModel();
t.set1(rs.getDate(1));
t.set2(rs.getDouble(2));
...
...
t.set60(rs.getString(60));
reportModelList.add(t)

}}finally {
DbUtils.closeQuietly(rs);
}
```

Comment: Try to initialize your `reportModelList` list with a big size like 800000.

Comment: What database driver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three suggestions.

1. As @Luiggi Mendoza writes as a comment, initialize your List with a large initial buffer, so it isn't reallocating and copying all day.
2. Depending on your DB and JDBC driver, you may get a speedup with `ps.setFetchSize(50000);` (Play around with constant.) If your fetch size is small you are doing a lot of I-want-more round-trips to your server.
3. **Don't guess which step is the bottleneck; use a profiler.**

Comment: I will try the fetchSize and a profiler. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: This sounds like a lot like your JVM is hitting its heap memory limit. Try increasing the JVMs maximum size so it can comfortably hold the records in memory.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to measures suggested by @Andrew Lazarus, use a memory profiler to see if this problem is caused by excessive garbage collection overheads.

---

However, I'm doubtful that giving a good size hint for the list will make a significant difference.  If you are using an `ArrayList`, the automatic resizing strategy is to double the allocation each time.  If you analyse it, that means that a list element (reference) is copied less than 2 times (on average) during the process of building the list.  The time to do that extra copying is small compared with the reported 2 hour run time.

Comment: Yes, I am using an ArrayList. I will try the memory profiler and get back. THanks for your suggestions.